# Match values from 3 non-adjacent columns

Tags: google-sheets, match

I want to count how many times values in column A match values in column C and and values in column E.

In this example spreadsheet, I want to count how many times the Coin Toss Caller (column A) won the Coin toss (column C) and won the game (column H). I know the result should be 2

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wamf.png)

I know that counting how many matches in two columns is very easy using Sumproduct. For example, this function is easy for two columns =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A21=C2:C21))
But now I want to see if the values also match a third column. Not so easy. FYI: I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=sumproduct((A2:A=D2:D)*(A2:A=H2:H),A2:A<>"")
```